# Silverlight Unit Test Framework Rerun Tests

Tags: silverlight, unit-testing, visual-studio-2010

Ok, maybe this is a really dumb question and I'm just not seeing the button...but how do I rerun checked tests in the SL Unit Testing application UI?

I launch the Unit Test App, let it run the tests.....then I can even check or uncheck certain tests when it completes....but how do I rerun those checked tests without restarting the whole darn thing? I just don't see a button "Run Selected Tests".....

Comment: This was back in SL2 days...but I would click the Test header and it would expand the details for the given test, there was then a link to rerun that specific test...how it functions now may be differently.

Comment: I dun see it :( ...could you be a bit more specific? Where is the Test Header? I have a tree view where I can select the tests via checkbox...and when I click on one it changes the content to info about the test on the right... but I don't see a run test button in either place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, I really hope I'm being stupid about this.

I posted the same question on CodePlex, got not answer. I sent a direct email to the creator of the framework, got no answer.

This tells me some of a couple of things:

1. I'm really so dumb that I've missed something terribly obvious.
2. No one really uses Silverlight for production applications or at least none that require unit testing, so no-one really knows the answer here.
3. Microsoft's commitment to Silverlight and support for it is sub-standard, at best.
4. I've just gotten unlucky in my hopes for support on this matter.

That said, I found an answer myself. In App.xaml.cs:

```
private UnitTestPage _page;
```

In Application_Startup:

```
RootVisual = _page = (TestPage) UnitTestSystem.CreateTestPage();
```

Add a button or a right click handler or something, then call

```
_page.UnitTestHarness.Run();
```

Hopefully this helps someone else.